# Rate Limit on Play Requests

Tags: android, soundcloud

I am developing a Music Application for Android using SoundCloud HTTP API. I read about Rate Limit from https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits.

So My Questions is that:

(1) How to check that Whether Limit is exceeds or not?

(2) I checked that If Limit is exceeds then Track API give a response like below json

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "meta": {
                "rate_limit": {
                    "bucket": "by-client",
                    "max_nr_of_requests": 15000,
                    "time_window": "PT24H",
                    "name": "plays"
                },
                "remaining_requests": 0,
                "reset_time": "2016/12/02 10:21:55 +0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But, If Limit is not exceed then how to check?

Also, another Question is

(3) How to play Track Streaming URL on Media Player?

Comment: There is no part in SoundCloud API documentation that specifically points to such endpoint. As far as I have searched, only thing you could do is to check if you have response with code 429, but agreed, this is not enough.

Comment: Yes I know that, It would be great, if there another options available. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=xxxxx&q=noah&limit=1

Note: xxxxx: Fill with your SoundCloud API